# PostgreSql installation issues for MacOS

Tags: postgresql

I want to install PostgreSQL on my Macbook Pro ( M1 Silicon Chip ) but I could not make it done.

What I have done:

- Downloaded postgresql and installed.
- Downloaded postgres command line for brew.
- Tried to start by `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` and getting error: `pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory`.
- Tried to define a directory for the db by `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres` and getting error: `zsh: killed     initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macos, i highly recommend you the postgres app: https://postgresapp.com/

Comment: That really works :) Thanks. Just an info, I need a GUI for this and I installed Valentino Studio. Postgreapp is just an PostgreSQL runner.